# Adding the calculated sum of a list to another list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of `int` .. How can i sum all the numbers in the list and get the result ?

```
List<int> FineListy = new List<int>();
```

Comment: First, dont name your variables the exact same thing (with different casing).  This is a _horrible_ idea.  Next, if `fineList` is a list of `int`, why are you converting it again in your loop?  The code and question make very little sense, I suggest you edit it

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code...

Comment: okay. edited. :3

Comment: Did you think of debugging your code to understand it's behavior? You want to sum up all the items in the first list and add the sum to the second list? Then all you need is a variable `sum` and initialize it to 0 and inside for loop you do `sum += fineList[I];` and add the sum to the list outside the for loop. `FineList.Add(sum);`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that sounds exactly. let me try

Comment: @DailyTecho check Johns answer.  Its exactly what you need to solve your problem and make your code better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues.

```
List<int> FineListy = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < fineList.Count(); i++)
{
    if (fineList[i] > 0)
    {
        FineListy.Add((fineList[i] += fineList[i]));              
    }
}
```

Firstly: C# naming conventions are such that local variables should start with lowercase letters and be camelCased. I recommend naming your variables `totalsList` and `fineList` respectively. For the sake of simplicity, I will use your current naming conventions below.

Next, you're doing `FineListy.Add(fineList[i] += fineList[i]);` which is the same as:

```
fineList[i] = fineList[i] * 2;
FineListy.Add(fineList[i]);
```

And you're doing it in a loop, so you will simply get a list of all items multiplied by 2.

Now you could fix this like so:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < fineList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (fineList[i] > 0)
    {
        total += fineList[i];
    }
}
FineListy.Add(total);
```

But you can use LINQ to do the same in  a single line (I've split it across multiple lines to make it easier to read):

```
var total = fineList
                .Where(v => v > 0)
                .Sum();
FineListy.Add(total);
```

Or simply:

```
FineListy.Add(fineList.Where(v => v > 0).Sum());
```

Comment: This is also the only answer that truly answers the question

Comment: Actually `Count` *has* an optimization and first it checks if collection implements `IList` and if yes - it casts it to that in order to use `.Count` property (which is O(1) operation instead of O(N)). So no, you won't loop through the list.

Comment: @Fabjan I know, I've already found the relevant code and updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `int`, why not use `sum` function??

```
int sum = FineListy.Sum();
```

This will add up all the numbers and give you the expected result.Now i see you do an `If` check to see if the number is not 0.So,create a new list then and pass the numbers to the list only if it's greater than 0

```
List<int> NewList = new List<int>;

foreach (var number in IntegerList)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        NewList.Add(number);
    }
}
```

Finally get the sum total :

```
 int sum = NewList.Sum();
```

Or one-line LINQ solution :

```
 var result = fineList.Where(a => a > 0).Sum();
 NewList.Add(result );
```

Comment: This is missing a key piece of logic that the OP has included that your code has not

Comment: @maccettura,the OP only asked for how he could sum all the numbers in the list , what did i miss ?

Comment: The OP does a check inside the loop, your code omits that check.  If that check is not done then the sum would not be the same as it is with it...

Comment: @maccettura,please take a look at the answer now :)

Comment: Remember that LINQ's `Where()` exists, which would be a pure LINQ solution.

Comment: @maccettura,added linq solution , u can take a look at it now .... I was the first one to answer this qs, back then , the qs was not clear at all so i missed a few points...I'm glad that u pointed the, out :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it doubles, because that's what you do here :

```
FineListy.Add((fineList[i] += fineList[i]));
```

You say : "Add me `fineList[i]` + `fineList[i]` to my resulting collection `FineListy`"
So you got all elements doubled.

If you want to add values you don't need list just a variable to store it and LINQ `.Sum()` method

P.S.
I mean either one of these two (as others suggested):

```
FineListy.Add(fineList.Sum());
```

Or

```
int sum = fineList.Sum();
```

Comment: You pointed out the solution but you may get downvotes as you didn't really mention the solution(i mean the code) itself..Please edit your answer :)

Comment: @zackraiyan Might want to undo the upvote, this does not answer the OP's question.  (its missing a key item that the OP's code has that is not included here)

Comment: It gives the wrong answer for `100, -1, 200, 100` .